# How do I set favicon in Odoo / OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, favicon, openerp-8

How do I set a favicon for the web/e-commerce frontend of Odoo 8?

Ideally without changing Odoo core files, i.e. I do not simply want to overwrite `addons/web/static/src/img/favicon.ico`.

(This is Odoo 8, August 2014. It's likely that it will be easier to change the favicon in future versions.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to override the `web` module with your own module. You can add a line like

```
'data': [ 'views/website_templates.xml' ]
```

in your `__openerp__.py`.

Put your favicon at `static/src/img/favicon.ico` and add a template to `views/website_templates`:

```
<template id="MYSITE_layout" inherit_id="website.layout" name="MYSITE layout" priority="17">
    <xpath expr="//head//link" position="after">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/MYSITE_web/static/src/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: It looks like this is the correct answer, but why can't I do this? It says "AssertionError: Document does not comply with schema" ... WHAT DO I DO?! :(

Answer (score 3):

Favicon is set in `<head>` html section, that is stored in template, and link there is hardcoded to point to `/web/static/src/img/favicon.ico` (see [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml)), so if you want to change it you have to change either icon file itself or change proper template to point to icon file you want.